# Can I determine program bottleneck based on system time vs cpu?

Tags: multithreading, system, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I'm running a DNA aligner which can utilized multiple threads. Currently doing 16 on a computer cluster.  Anecdotally I feel like increasing the amount of threads or even ram space has a diminishing return. Does my benchmark below proof this point? since CPU time < System Time by a wide margin.  In other words does this mean that the limiting factor is some other issue like storage so that utilizing more threads will not help at this point?  My goal is to reduce total running time.

thank you.

```
 User Time        = 1:06:03:35
 System Time      = 04:35:24
 Wallclock Time   = 08:24:50
 CPU              = 1:10:38:59
```

Comment: Uhm, CPU time is much *more* than the system time? Out of 34 hours, 4 hours were spent in the OS, so probably with I/O and swapping. 30 hours were spent computing, that is 88%, quite reasonable.

Comment: You always should profile you application. Use vtune or similar to do so and you will know you bottlenecks, otherwise you'll waste you time.